# Function does not reduce in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, aggregate

I have a problem with Pandas aggregate.

I have 4 columns with "int" type and one as a string.
I want those with int to sum, that one with string to get unique.

I have used next function:

```
df = df.groupby(['Time', 'Id', 'Object', 'Alias', 'Type'],as_index=False).agg(lambda x : x.sum() if x.dtype=='int' else x.unique())
```

But I'm getting next error:

```
ValueError: Function does not reduce
```

I have found some similar questions but each of them has only one operation in an aggregate function. Not sure how to use any advice in my case.

Comment: Where's your data?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `x.nunique()` ?

Answer (score 0):

`unique` is not an aggregating function. Aggregating functions reduce the dimension of the data, e.g. `sum` reduces a list of numbers to a single number, whereas `unique` reduces a list to a potentially smaller list.

```py
my_series = pd.Series([1, 2, 1, 3])  # 1-D
my_series.sum()  # 7, a scalar
my_series.unique()  # [1, 2, 3] still 1-D
```